# design the data structures for an online book

Tags: oop

```
public class Book {
 private long ID;
 private String details;
 private static Set books;

 public Book(long iD, String details) { ... }
 public static void addBook(long iD, String details){....}

 public void update() { }
 public static void delete(Book b) { books.remove(b); }
 public static Book find(long id){....}
 };

 public class User {
 private long ID;
 private String details;
 private int accountType;
 private static Set users;

 public Book searchLibrary(long id) { return Book.find(id); }
 public void renewMembership() { ... }

 public static User find(long ID) {....}

 public static void addUser(long ID, String details,int accountType) {
 users.add(new User(ID, details, accountType));
 }

 public User(long iD, String details, int accountType) { ... }
 }

 public class OnlineReaderSystem {
 private Book b;
 private User u;
 public OnlineReaderSystem(Book b, User u) { ... }
 public void listenRequest() { }
 public Book searchBook(long ID) { return Book.find(ID); }
 public User searchUser(long ID){ return User.find(ID); }
 public void display() { }
 }
```

This is the standard solution found for the question of data structures for designing the online book reader.My question is why we require to declare static data member(**private static Set books**) books within the book class(same goes for static member in user class). What is the advantage of this approach ? 
(removed some of the function definitions so that we can avoid Java/C++/C# related answers, I just hope that static variables are pretty much available in all these object oriented language)

Comment: Is this Java? C#? Where did you find this "standard solution"?

Answer (score 0):

This code is using a class `Book` to store all the books in your application, and similarly a User holds a `static` `Set` of all users. When the data member is `static`, all book instances will share the same `Set` of books, and similarly for users.

This means you have to write using code as

```
Book.find(1, "details"); //assuming format for call, given language not stated
```

This does feel slightly odd.

An alternative would be to form a collection of books, users etc and search that without making the data `static` in the classes.